# Rails 3 fb_graph posting to timeline doesn't show image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timeline

I am using the following code to publish a post to a users wall via the publish_stream permission:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(token)
        me.feed!(
            :message => 'message'
            :image => [valid_url],
            :link => [valid_url],
            :name => 'Test',
            :description => 'Description'
            )
```

When I post to a users wall that does NOT have timeline activated, it works brilliantly. When I post to a users timeline, the post shows (message, link, name, description), but there is no accompanying image.

Has anyone run in to this problem? Is there a different parameter that needs to get pushed to get an image to accompany the post on the timeline? Does the gem need updating?

PS: The fb_graph documentation says to use

```
:picture => 'https://graph.facebook.com/matake/picture',
```

which does not work either

Answer (score 2):

I'm fb_graph developer.
I tried reproduce this, but this code worked for me now.

```
me.feed!(
  :message => 'I posted an update',
  :picture => 'http://matake.jp/images/nov.gif',
  :link => 'http://fbgraphsample.heroku.com',
  :name => 'FbGraph Sample',
  :description => 'test test'
)
```

ps.
`:image` didn't work.

Comment: this solution works !! :) and thanks @nov for the gem `fb_graph`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by leaving out the picture parameter and instead adding a link tag to the head of the page pointed to by ":link"

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://stackoverflow.com/images/logo.gif" />
```

I got pointed in the right direction with [this post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image).